# How to reset ListViewItem styles?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, styles, listviewitem

I have an xaml style so defined :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">[...]</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" x:Key="track_selected">[...]</Style>
```

And here's the code to programmatically apply the "track_selected" style for a listviewitem

```
((ListViewItem)lv_tracklist.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(currentTrackIndex)).Style = FindResource("track_selected") as Style;
```

My question is, how to reset all listviewitem inside mylistview to its default style, which is the first one of the above listed?

Comment: Why do you want do set style from code behind? Did you consider using Triggers? Their usage will solve your question

Comment: ((ListViewItem)lv_tracklist.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(currentTrackIndex)).Style = null;

Comment: Thanks colinsmith.

Do I have to cycle all listviewItem
for (int i=lv_tracklist.Items.Count; --i >= 0;)
            {..}

or there's a  faster solution ?

Comment: Sorry, but looking better this does not solve my problem, because setting style to null does not back to default style which is 

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">[...]</Style>

but it reset to the default wpf style :-(

Answer (score 2):

Although there are exceptions, manipulating the Views object in code behind is not recommended. This should be done in the `xaml` file.

This example is **bad coding practice** when using WPF.

Switching between `Styles` is the best to use `StyleSelectors`.
In your case set the ItemContainerStyleSelector property of your ListView.

```
<Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
   <!-- Setters and Triggers -->
</Style>

<Style x:Key="TrackSelectedStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
   <!-- Setters and Triggers -->
</Style>

<example:TrackSelectionStyleSelectorx:Key="myContainerStyleSelector"
ItemsStyle ="{StaticResource ItemStyle}"
TrackSelectedStyle ="{StaticResource TrackSelectedStyle}"/>

<ListView ... ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource myContainerStyleSelector}"/>
```

And the `StyleSelector` class (put it in separate .cs file):

```
public class TrackSelectionStyleSelector: StyleSelector
{
   public Style ItemsStyle {get; set;}
   public Style TrackSelectedStyle {get; set;}

   public override Style SelectStyle( object item, DependencyObject container )
   {
     if ( /* isTrackSelected logic */ )
        return TrackSelectedStyle;

     return ItemsStyle;
   }

}
```

Don't forget to cast the item parameter to the type of your ListViewItems contents type.